# Request to AWS SES API failed. Reason: The security token included in the request is invalid when trying to send email with Localstack ses + Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, localstack

I'm trying to send an email with Localstack ses service in my URL project, but I keep getting the error message about my security token even if it's absolutely the same as in my configuration file.

Here is my mail.php file:

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'ses'),
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
],
'ses' => [
'transport' => 'ses',
],`
```

My service.php file:

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'xxxxxxxx'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxx'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'eu-west-2'),
],
```

Here I've tried to create an IAM user and use those keys for my keys and I've added it as default just for the tests

My .env file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=123
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xyz
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
AWS_BUCKET=inno-laravel
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://localstack:4566
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true
```

Here in Docker file I'm setting up my credetionals:

```
FROM localstack/localstack:1.2.0

COPY ./assets/* /root/.aws/

RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id 123 \
&& aws configure set aws_secret_access_key xyz \
&& aws configure set region eu-west-2 \
&& aws configure set output json
```

In the assets folder there are 2 files in which I'm setting up the keys, with S3 bucket it woks fine but I can't manage it to work with emails ses service

I've tried to send email directly from my localstack container but unfortunately no access even if it's showing no errors
Here is an  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef5Kp.png) with command and result for it

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the issue. If you are using Laravel 10 you also need to add `'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),` parameter to your service.php file inside ses and clarify it in the .env file or directly here. Without it I guess I was trying to connect to the AWS service which I didn't need and didn't have of course